# How to determine the visible area of QQuickPaintedItem?

Tags: qt, qml

Is there an equivalent of [Win32 GetUpdateRect function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-getupdaterect) in QML? For example, if a control derived from QQuickPaintedItem is inside Flickable is there a way to get the smallest rectangle that should be redrawn in

```
QQuickPaintedItem::paint(QPainter *painter)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `QQuickPaintedItem::update()`,  the given `QRect` parameter will be set as *clip bounding rect* for your `QPainter` in `QQuickPaintedItem::paint`.

So, if you want to redraw a specific region of your item, just call `QQuickPaintedItem::update()` with the rect you want to repaint.

```
item->update(QRect(10, 20, 30, 20));

void CharacterItem::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    qDebug() << painter->clipBoundingRect() << painter->clipPath();
}
```

It will display:

```
QRectF(10,20 30x20)

QPainterPath: Element count=5
 -> MoveTo(x=10, y=20)
 -> LineTo(x=40, y=20)
 -> LineTo(x=40, y=40)
 -> LineTo(x=10, y=40)
 -> LineTo(x=10, y=20)
```